# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name Null on Linux Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, .net-5

My app a Blazor app with .net 5.0 code. The app is hosted inside a Linux docker container

I have the following code to extract the user from the logged user

```
public class ContextHelper : IContextHelper 
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public ContextHelper(IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContext = HttpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetUserName()
    {
        return _httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

in my startup I have the following setup

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate(options =>
{
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
    {
        options.EnableLdap("someinternaladdy.org");
    }
});

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IContextHelper , ContextHelper>();
```

This works fine in windows, but when I run my app in a Linux container its null.

I have the following in LaunchSettings

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15652",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "CustomerCare.Gui": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true
    }
  }
}
```

and the following docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CustomerCare.Gui.csproj", "CustomerCare.Gui/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CustomerCare.Gui.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CustomerCare.Gui"
RUN dotnet build "CustomerCare.Gui.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CustomerCare.Gui.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CustomerCare.Gui.dll"]
```

Comment: The identity depends on many factors. On Windows, you run the app on IIS? If yes anonymous authentication or windows auth? Which is the user of apppool? You run the app on Kestrel? Do you have a custom authentication or windows authentication? Try to update the question (not post a comment below) with 1. The server (Kestrel, Nginx, IIS) 2. Use some kind of authentication? 3. All info necessary to better understand your problem.

Comment: hi @Max i added more info

Comment: From the updated question I see `iisSettings` is the only setting to have **windows authentication**, I think you use it to run your app on the local machine. **Linux** doesn't have **Windows** Users concept